# PostgreSQL join query issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning PostgreSQL and was practicing questions.

I am stuck at this question [here](https://www.w3resource.com/postgresql-exercises/join/postgresql-join-exercise-2.php)

My Solution does not seem to work and I am not sure why:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name 
FROM employees 
JOIN departments ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id;
```

Their solution:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, department_id, department_name 
FROM employees 
JOIN departments USING (department_id);
```

I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: What is your question?  You have a solution that works in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution does not work because the field names are ambiguous. Try prefixing like this

```
SELECT 
  employees.first_name, 
  employees.last_name, 
  departments.department_id, 
  departments.department_name 
FROM employees 
JOIN departments ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id;
```

The problem does not appear when you use `USING`, because then there will be only a single `department_id` column in the join result.

Comment: you might also have to specify the join type. e.g., "INNER JOIN" or "LEFT JOIN" instead of just JOIN.

Comment: Thanks alot. Since the website does not show the error, I could not figure it out.
One **Question** , isn't `JOIN` by default mean `INNER JOIN` ?

Comment: JOIN might well be INNER JOIN in Postgres. That's allowed in some SQL variants for sure; I'm just never sure which.

Comment: @Aadmaa . . . `JOIN` *means* `INNER JOIN`.  The `INNER` is totally redundant.

Comment: Thx @GordonLinoff - I didn't realize it was the actual SQL standard. But I confirmed here:  
http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

"If a <qualified join> is specified and a <join type> is not
            specified, then INNER is implicit."